# #ifdef __cplusplus nuisance: How to prevent extra indenting?

Tags: indentation, c

If you ever wrote header files that have to be used by both C compiler and C++ compiler, you'd encounter this particular `ifdef`.  This construct causes one to insert extra curly braces in the header file, which later makes Emacs attempt to indent everything one level deeper to the right.

Is there any way to make Emacs recognize this ifdef and ignore the indenting created by it?

Here's an example:

```c
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* Emacs will try to indent everything here one level to the right */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [`inextern-lang` offset](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/External-Scope-Symbols.html#External-Scope-Symbols) to 0 in [`c-offsets-alist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Syntactic-Symbols.html) for your indentation style.

Here's some code adapted from my own init file that creates a C style called `wvxvw` and defines it to have 4-space indents, indented `case` statements inside `switch` blocks, non-indented labels, and non-indented `extern` blocks (the other settings are just to illustrate some of the possibilities).

```
(defun cc-style-make-my-wvxvw ()
  (let ((entry (assoc "wvxvw" c-style-alist)))
    (unless entry
      (setq entry (cons "wvxvw" nil))
      (setq c-style-alist (cons entry c-style-alist)))
    (setcdr entry '((c-basic-offset . 4)
                    (c-offsets-alist
                     (label . 0)
                     (case-label . +)
                     (inextern-lang . 0)
                     )))))
(eval-after-load "cc-styles" '(cc-style-make-wvxvw))
```

The obvious follow-up is how to get this style to apply automatically. There are multiple solutions; what I do is, at the top of the directory where I want to use this style, I use the following `.dir-locals.el`:

```
((c-mode
  (c-file-style . "wvxvw")))
```

If other people working on the same code use Emacs, you may want to share these definitions. You can put any string in `c-file-style` in a file or directory local variable declaration, but it's annoying for people who don't have the style name defined. Unfortunately, you can't define a style or tweak offsets through file-local variables. So if you want to share the style, you need all Emacs users to copy the style definition to (a file loaded by) their own init file.

Comment: This is really awesome!